# Java, SWT how to make RowLayout working within a ScrolledCompositite?

Tags: swt

I had a long fight getting into the guts of SWT, and I'm, not really half done with it (angry face here).

I have Group with RowLayout, that wraps. The group is within other Composites, and might get too large for the display, so I wrapped it by a ScrolledComposite.

This is where the trouble starts.

Whatever is within a ScrolledComposite gets its way in way of width and height, whatever the dimensions might be. It has some logic, as the SrolledComposite can take care of that with ScrollBars.

The thing is (or at least looks to me like), that if a RowLayout can have its way with width, **it will never, ever, wrap,** and this is not what it should do inside a parent that is itself restricted.

What is the intended solution to this problem?

Comment: It seems you want to use the ScrolledComposite in 'browser mode' Did you have a look here: https://www.codeaffine.com/2016/03/01/swt-scrolledcomposite/

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann I have seen that before and have reviewed it no. I can't make sense of it. It does not use as content a Composite with RowLayout, to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout of the control that is set as the *content* of the scrolled composite (i.e. the argument of `sc.setContent`) doesn't matter. A layout affects only the immediate children of the control that was set to.

Most likely, your group widget doesn't adapt to the size of the containing scrolled composite. Note: it often helps to color relevant widgets differently (with `setBackground`) to see which space they actually take.

The following snippet creates a `ScrolledComposite` that scrolls vertically, if the `content` control is larger than the client area of the scrolled composite.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("ScrolledComposite in 'browser' mode");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    Composite content = new Composite(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
    content.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
        Label label = new Label(content, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("label " + i);
    }
    scrolledComposite.setContent(content);
    scrolledComposite.addListener(SWT.Resize, event -> {
        int width = scrolledComposite.getClientArea().width;
        scrolledComposite.setMinSize(content.computeSize(width, SWT.DEFAULT));
    });
    scrolledComposite.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolledComposite.setExpandVertical(true);
    shell.setSize(600, 300);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

The code uses the 'browser mode' as described in the [JavaDoc](https://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/documentation/2.0/html/plugins/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/ScrolledComposite.html)

> Set the minimum size of the control and the ScrolledComposite will show scroll bars if the visible area is less than the minimum size of the control and it will expand the size of the control if the visible area is greater than the minimum size. This requires invoking both setMinWidth(), setMinHeight() and setExpandHorizontal(), setExpandVertical().

Setting the `minSize` in a resize-listener ensures that the minimum size adapts to the size of the scrolled composite.

Comment: Your code is working, but I don't understand why yours is and mine is not. Let me have some time to compare these.

Comment: Your example code still works when the ScrolledComposite is within a Group, not directly within the shell, which I have fond to be a spoiler for most of the primitive examples from the net. I think you put me on the right track.

Comment: The expanded code works, when the enclosing Group has FillLayout. It fails for GridLayout, with which I usually work.

Comment: If the scrolled composite should take the entire space of the group's client area, then `FillLayout` is the right choice.

Comment: I accept the answer because the code is working. But I still don't understand WHY.